# Renaming a column in a column

Tags: python, pandas

So I want to rename a column in a column

```
Student["Name"] = Student["Name"].replace({"Anurag":"Rahul"})
```

I have done this and its not working .Is there any alternate way?

Comment: I guess `Student["Name"] = Student["Name"].replace({"Anurag":"Rahul"}, regex=True)`

Comment: thnx a lot   it worked